# WSRP Portlets in Oracle WebCenter : Images referenced from CSS files aren't loaded

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, portlet, webcenter

If a WSRP portlet displays a jsp page that references a css file which references an image, the image can't be loaded because the url in the css can't be found.
The url in the css is a relative one: ../images/image.gif.

**Details of my problem**

I have developed a JSR168 portlet (Java Portlet Standard) and I want to deploy it in Oracle WebCenter 11g (among other JSR-complaint portal servers)

My portlet displays a jsp which references a css file and this css references a few images. All these resources (images, css, jsps, etc) are contained into the war file of my portlet.

When I load the portlet in a WebCenter page, the css file is loaded correctly, but the images referenced by this css file don't.

The reason is that to generate the css, WebCenter generates a long url:
http://localhost:8888/webcenter/resourceproxy/~.portletId~3D~252Foracle~252Fadf~252Fportlet~252FscopedMD~252Fs8bba98ff_4cbb_40b8_beee_296c916a23ed~252Fportlets~252Fclients3_366e85fa_e823_48ac_b37a_9890375111ab~26clientId... (its way longer)

But inside this css file, there are relative paths to the images. And when the browser tries to load them, the url is:
http://localhost:8888/webcenter/resourceproxy/img/sprite.png
which doesn't exist.

What can I do to make WebCenter load the images in my css files correctly?

**How do I deploy my portlet into Oracle WebCenter**
I explain this, in case I should do it differently.

- I convert my portlet into to a WSRP portlet by executing
  java -jar wsrp-predeploy.jar source EAR target EAR
  as explained in http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/webcenter.1111/e12405/wcadm_portlet_prod.htm#CHDECJHI)
- I deploy it into WebLogic with the WebLogic Console.
- I register a Portlet Producer using the Enterprise Manager 11g Fusion MiddleWare Control.
- I add the portlet to the main page of the WebCenter Spaces

**My Environment**

WebCenter Suite (11.1.1.2.0) + WebLogic Server (10.3.2)
S.O: Windows XP SP3

**Thanks in advance for your time.**

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue. Well, this will not give you a solution, but will explain you why...

> One of the goals of an aggregated page is a common look-and-feel across the Portlets contained on that page [A500]. This not only affects the decorations around the Portlets, but also their content. Using a common CSS style sheet for all Portlets, and defining a set of standard styles, provides this common look-and-feel without requiring the Portlets to generate Consumer-specific markup. Portlets SHOULD use the CSS style definitions from this specification in order to participate in a uniform display of their content by various Consumers. For markup types that support CSS stylesheets, Consumers MUST supply a CSS stylesheet to the End-User's agent with definitions for the classes defined in [Section 9.5] of this specification.

I think somebody had made mistake when writing the spec.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

My portlet works fine in IBM WebSphere Portal, JBoss Portal and LifeRay Portal.
The problem only appears in Oracle WebCenter. So I think the problem is in WebCenter.

Although JSR-168 and 286 define some CSS styles, in my case I need another CSS to render the YUI table (Yahoo JavaScript library) properly.

P.S
A few weeks back I asked the same question in the Oracle forum, but I didnt' get any answer :-( http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=4032022

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the relative path like ../../css/ instead use <%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/, within your CSS you can still keep the relative path of your images ../../images/.

Comment: I think that I con only put `<%=request.getContextPath()%>` inside JSPs files, not CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure the application server to push CSS files through the engine the same way you do JSPs. In this case you should be able to have those tags compiled.

Comment: Thanks AJ. Can you give more details about how to do this? I don't know much about the administration of Oracle WebCenter.